# Update dom according to function return value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bind

I am trying to make a list where you can only have one active element. The state updates just like it is supposed to, but the isActive function only activates at first and then doesn't when the state changes.

Here is a working example of what I want to do in ES5: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRWqQX

My code in ES6 which doesn't work. The isActive function doesn't trigger on state change.

```
import React from 'react'

class RadioButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isActive = this.isActive.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      selected: ""
    }
  }
  isActive(value) {
    if (this.state.selected === value) 
      return 'active';
    else 
      return null;
  }
  makeActive(value) {
    this.state = {
      selected: value
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.isActive("option1")} onClick={this.makeActive.bind(this, 'option1')} > option 1</div>
        <div className={this.isActive("option2")} onClick={this.makeActive.bind(this, 'option2')} > option 2</div>
        <div className={this.isActive("option3")} onClick={this.makeActive.bind(this, 'option3')} > option 3</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RadioButtons;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change state in React using the [`setState` function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

```
this.setState({selected: value});
```

Reassigning a new value to `this.state` doesn't trigger a re-render.

Comment: Changing this.state to this.setState did not help :/ The class still doesn't show up in the div.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I had left the equal sign between setState and braces. Doesn't give an error, but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the property `this.state` you want to use the method

```
this.setState({selected: value});
```

The method also does some extra functionality, like re-rendering and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
  makeActive(value) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    })
  }
```